# How to change permissions of all channels of a guild with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to change permissions of all channels of a server from Read messages = True to False. Basically I don't want users with default-role to be able to see any of the channel.
What I wrote:

```
@bot.command()
async def maintainance(ctx):
    channel = ctx.guild.channels
    perms = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    perms.read_messages=False
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=perms)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="<a:tick:748476262640779276>")
```

error I get:

```
Ignoring exception in command maintainance:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Rohit\Desktop\discord bots\tutorial bot\bot.py", line 23, in maintainance
    perms = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'overwrites_for'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'overwrites_for'
```

I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwrites are per channel so you need to do the `get_overwrites` *inside* the for loop, some psuedocode would look like

```
for every channel:
    overwrites = get_overwrites()
    overwrites.send_message = False
    channel.set_permissions(default_role, overwrites=overwrites)
```

Another thing is that you should do `ctx.message.add_reaction()` outside the loop to avoid trying to add the same reaction multiple times